# 3D visual effects on videos

Tags: unity, 3d, graphics, graphic-effects, video

I'm trying to get some hands-on experience with 3D visual effects on videos. Similar to those AR apps, I want to add a 3D model with effects, say a dragon, to a video. Something like this famous demo:

https://youtu.be/u5hQpRbHERg

But I don't really want to make it this fancy with camera tracking. I like to start with the simplest approach- probably just placing a dragon on the field (like its last scenes) with fixed camera.

What's the best way to do it? Some tutorials would be very helpful.

Comment: Presumably you started by adding your video player into your Unity scene along with the 3D model you want to animate, and using Unity's animation tools to move it around the way you want. Where did you run into trouble with this - what's the next step we can help you complete?

Comment: Is there any tools other than Unity? Simpler for beginners. I just want to add a static dragon.

Comment: You asked in a game development site and tagged your question "Unity" so I assumed you wanted to use Unity. If you're not interested in making an AR app or game, you might want to ask on a video production forum instead. You've been here long enough to know that this is not the place to ask for software recommendations.